# Starting new activity from recyclerview adapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-intent

I am reading data from firebase real time database to a recyclerview and on the recyclerview item there a button to start a new activity. I have this onClick method

```
public void bookBtnOnClick(final int position){
        mBookButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mContext.startActivity(new Intent(this,ReservationForm.class));
                }
        });
    }
```

But it cannot resolve intent constructer

Comment: What is your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try-->

```
Intent intent =  new Intent(context, ReservationForm.class);
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
mcontext.startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of **this** try `mContext` as i guess you are trying it inside Adapter class

```
  mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ReservationForm.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Change **'this'** to **'mContext'**;

```
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ReservationForm.class));
```

Answer (score 1):

Adding more to @S.ambika's answer.

Change `this` to `mContext` when creating `Intent`.

```
mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ReservationForm.class));
```

As when you use `this`, it will give the current context. In your case `this` is returning the context of `onClick` and for starting a new Activity, we need the context of `Activity`.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
public void bookBtnOnClick(final int position){
     mContext.startActivity(new Intent(context, ReservationForm.class));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How's about this

```
Intent intent = new Intent (v.getContext(), ReservationForm.class);
v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Define Context mContext;  on starting of adapter and in constructor use this.mcontext=mcontext;
```

mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext,ReservationForm.class));